# Bibliographic entry for a pseudymous work with known real author

Tags: citations, citation-style, bibtex

*This question is the bibliographic pendant to [this question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/76503/citing-article-where-listed-author-is-pseudonym).*

Let us suppose I write an academic paper where I cite the [well known](http://the-toast.net/2014/12/09/linguist-explains-syntax-f-word/) paper *English sentences without overt grammatical subject*  ([pdf](http://babel.ucsc.edu/~hank/quangphucdong.pdf)), written by [James d. McCawley](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_D._McCawley) under the pseudonym Quang Phúc Đông. What is the bes way to format the bibliography?

- [1] Đông Q. P., “English sentences without overt grammatical subject”, doi: 10.1075/z.63.06don. Actually written by McCawlay, J.D. under pseudonym
- [2] Đông Q. P. (alias McCawlay, J.D.), “English sentences without overt grammatical subject”, doi: 10.1075/z.63.06don.
- [3] McCawlay, J.D. (as Đông Q. P.), “English sentences without overt grammatical subject”, doi: 10.1075/z.63.06don.
- Something else ?

I want to make both the name and pseudonym appear in the bibliography.

Bonus question: Once the “academically correct” solution is known, how to implement it in a `bibtex` bibliography?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The "academically correct" solution is usually to format that bibliographical item as any other item, with the name which appears on the paper (this is also remarked in the answers to the linked question). Then, you can add a bibliographical note saying that the name is a pseudonym: in `bibtex` you can do this by means of the field `note`. However, about this, take into account the objections that have been pointed out in the answers and comments to the linked question.

The above solution would roughly correspond to your [1], with the exact details depending on the chosen style.

Of course, if you are writing a paper for a journal, the style guide might require a different formatting or might not accept notes.

**Edit:** I've checked *The Chicago Manual of Style*, 16th edition, and it suggest a slightly different style, more similar to your example [2]:

> ***14.81 Pseudonyms -- unknown authorship.*** If an author's real name is not known, *pseud.* (roman, in brackets) may follow the name. (In a
>   text citation, *pseud.* is omitted.)

and

> ***14.82 Pseudonyms -- known authorship.*** A widely used pseudonym is generally treated as if it were the author's real name.
>
> [...]
>
> The real name, if of interest to readers, may follow the pseudonym in
>   brackets.

According to the above, your example would become:

Đông, Q. P. [McCawlay, J.D.], “English sentences without overt grammatical subject”, doi: 10.1075/z.63.06don.

The *New Oxford Style Manual* suggests the same format.

For what concerns LaTeX, if you want to follow the above format, it appears that the [`biblatex-chicago`](http://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex/exptl/biblatex-contrib/biblatex-chicago/doc/biblatex-chicago.pdf) supports it. However, it is probably not applicable to specific publications. For instance, the [IEEE BibTeX style](ftp://tug.ctan.org/pub/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/IEEEtran/bibtex/IEEEtran_bst_HOWTO.pdf) does not support explicitly pseudonyms, but it has a `note` field. The people at [TeX.SE](https://tex.stackexchange.com/) can probably give you better information on which is the best way to implement that specific format.

Comment: The common-sense approach as well as the academically correct one, happily :-). As a good (if extreme example) - consider what you'd do if writing a study of, say, dystopian literary fiction. The bibliography would look very strange if it had "Blair, E. "Nineteen Eighty-Four" (1949)" in it, even if everyone knows that's the author's real name...